# What are the alternatives for ffserver?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

Since the ffmpeg no longer support ffserver,  then which server could I use to steamming videos transcoded by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 13):

The shortest answer is taken from official [ffservers's page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver) and they propose to try an alternative such as [mkvserver_mk2](https://github.com/klaxa/mkvserver_mk2)​.

Another option found while reading mail archive is [Simple RTMP Server](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)

Give it a try.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't pretend on anything, it may be deleted. I answered cause usually I tend to help anyone + I was was searching for the same as OP asked, that why it's a short answer.